# How to use async class methods in APScheduler jobs?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, apscheduler

I'm using APScheduler's AsyncIOScheduler and AsyncIOExecutor as part of a bot. A simple test function, that sends a "pong" message after a few seconds, works fine, but async class methods do nothing, and log a RuntimeWarning that the coroutine was never awaited.

I'm using a fairly minimal APS setup, with a SQLite DB for a lightweight job persistence layer:

```py
def new_scheduler():
    jobstores = {
        "memory": MemoryJobStore(),
        "default": SQLAlchemyJobStore(url="sqlite:///.jobs.sqlite"),
    }
    executors = {
        "default": AsyncIOExecutor(),
    }
    return AsyncIOScheduler(
        jobstores=jobstores, executors=executors, timezone=datetime.timezone.utc
    )
```

The problem appears to come from using the class method, as scheduling a simple task, with an async function defined outside of any class, works fine.

The class method in question (`ModAction.lift`) is part of a base class for restrictions placed on a user, which is responsible for removing the restriction and deleting it from the database.

When I apply the restriction, if there is an expiration date attached, I create a job on the scheduler to call the `lift` class method, and store its ID, so we can cancel it if the restriction is manually lifted before it expires:

```py
class ModAction(Document): # Document inherits from pydantic.BaseModel, providing important fields and methods for interacting with the database.
    # FakeMember is a serialization class that reduces Members to a user and guild ID
    issuer: FakeMember
    target: FakeMember
    reason: Optional[str] = None
    expires: Optional[datetime.datetime] = None
    lift_job_id: Optional[str] = None

    async def apply(self, bot: Bot, no_dm: bool = False):
        if not no_dm:
            await try_dm(await self.target.get_or_fetch(bot), embeds=[self.dm_embed])
        if self.expires is not None and self.expires > now():
            self.lift_job_id = bot.scheduler.add_job(
                self.__class__.lift,
                kwargs={
                    "id": self.id,
                    "reason": "Expired",
                },
                trigger="date",
                next_run_time=self.expires,
            ).id
        await bot.log(embed=self.apply_log_embed(bot))
        await self.store(bot.db_connection)

    @classmethod
    @validate_call
    async def lift(
        cls,
        id: DocumentId,
        reason: Optional[str] = None,
        member: Optional[FakeMember] = None,
    ):
        from cogs.mod import _bot # The bot that loads the extension is stored in this global variable.

        self = await cls.fetch(id, _bot.db_connection)
        await _bot.log(embed=self.lift_log_embed(_bot, reason, member))
        await _bot.db_connection.delete(id)
```

Different mod actions have different ways of being enforced--hence me using class methods. Take, for example, a simple server ban:

```py
class ServerBan(ModAction):
    async def apply(self, bot: Bot, no_dm: bool = False):
        await super().apply(bot, no_dm)
        await self.target.get(bot).ban(reason=self.apply_audit_reason(bot))

    @classmethod
    @validate_call
    async def lift(
        cls,
        id: DocumentId,
        reason: Optional[str] = None,
        member: Optional[FakeMember] = None,
    ):
        from cogs.mod import _bot

        self: cls = await cls.fetch(id, _bot.db_connection)
        await super().lift(id, reason, member)
        await self.target.get(_bot).unban(
            reason=cls.lift_audit_reason(_bot, reason, member)
        )
```

Is this something with APS? With class methods? Or am I just using them wrong?
If needs be, I am open to trying other solutions for handling this problem--I am not particularly invested in using APScheduler, as the bot is still in early development.
Whether it be suggesting a fix for APS, or a whole new solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question again--I found a workaround. Instead of adding the class method as the job's callback directly, I instead created a static method for the auto-lift, that takes in the subclass as an argument, and calls the `lift` class method on the subclass. My final code looks like this:

```py
class ModAction(Document):
    """A base class for disciplinary actions issued by server staff against other members."""
    # --snip--
    async def apply(self, bot: Bot, no_dm: bool = False):
        if not no_dm:
            await try_dm(await self.target.get_or_fetch(bot), embeds=[self.dm_embed])
        if self.expires is not None and self.expires > now():
            self.lift_job_id = bot.scheduler.add_job(
                self.auto_lift,
                kwargs={"subclass": self.__class__, "id": self.id},
                trigger="date",
                next_run_time=self.expires,
            ).id
        await bot.log(embed=self.apply_log_embed(bot))
        await self.store(bot.db_connection)

    @staticmethod
    async def auto_lift(subclass: Type["ModAction"], id: DocumentId, reason = "Expired"):
        await subclass.lift(id, reason=reason)

    @classmethod
    @validate_call
    async def lift(
        cls,
        id: DocumentId,
        reason: Optional[str] = None,
        member: Optional[FakeMember] = None,
    ):
        from cogs.mod import _bot

        obj = await cls.fetch(id, _bot.db_connection)
        await _bot.log(embed=obj.lift_log_embed(_bot, reason, member))
        await _bot.db_connection.delete(id)
```